# Announcing a Pro Tempore election

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **April 22** to bring in one more moderator.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on April 22, users can [nominate themselves](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/election/1). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On April 29, if there are two or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidate. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on May 7.

(Note for current moderators: there's no need to nominate yourself even though you'll likely get an email saying you should. The system assumes the first election is a graduation election, which would mean moderators would need to be re-elected. This isn't that sort of election.)

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Comment: @Namaste: Feel free to copy [this basic meta post template](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4461/2019-moderator-election-qa-question-collection) to collect questions. Obviously there is plenty of time so it probably makes sense to post the actual questionnaire when nominations start.

Comment: @Namaste: Ah. I had lost track of which community we're on. That neatly illustrates the problem. In order to do more elections, we've cut back on non-essential steps for _pro tempore_ elections. As I say in the question, you can totally ask questions on candidates on meta. It's fine to just grab the standard questions if those are the ones you want to ask.

Answer (score 2):

I guess I'll bite with a question.  How was the decision to add precisely one (not zero, not two, etc.) new moderator(s) reached for MESE?  I honestly have no idea how SE handles moderator stuff, so this is not a question that has any preconceived answer  - but I couldn't find an answer to it on any of the linked posts, and I'd find it helpful.  Thanks!

Comment: Voodoo. ;-) Seriously, we want to have 3 active moderators on each site so that flags are handled and spam is cleaned out even when one or two people are on vacation or taking a break. At the moment, we have [two moderators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), so I want to add one more. The current moderators are doing great and there's not a ton of work, so this is a belt _and_ suspenders situation. (Fun fact, I accidentally scheduled an election with 0 slots earlier. I'm not sure how that'd work. ;-)

Comment: Ok, thanks, that explains - I didn't even know there were only two moderators.  I never see anything in the queues so I guess that is good :)

Comment: You can see the per site mods here: https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators At the start three were appointed. Jim Belk was the third. He resigned at some point and I think the plan was  to replace him. One could say that he now *finally* is replaced.

Comment: (Or will be when the election is over?)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously I don't read here enough. I thought I had to nominate myself, and I thought we were being taken down to just one moderator. (Yikes!) @quid helped me figure this out.

Comment: Sorry. I really need to get this quirk fixed. :-/