# 2019 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2019 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Answer (score 2):

Is it not possible to nominate others? I read all the pages but it looks like you can only nominate yourself. I think I am not in the top 3 candidates. Is there an accepted way to encourage someone to nominate themselves?

Comment: I imagine the self-nominations are to prevent the scenario of someone being voted in but never having wanted to do the job. Perhaps we can use comments on this post (not this answer of yours but the main post) to tag other users who we want to see nominate themselves.

Comment: My experience at Money.SE confirms that a 'draft' would be unwelcome. 2 or 3 members who are very vocal, in a positive way, yet every time I ask if they'd run for a Mod position, they tell me they don't want it.

Comment: I did as you suggested. You all have more SE experience than me (maybe?). Feel free to improve my question  as always. https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/610/nomination-suggestions-for-2019-moderator-election

Answer (score 2):

On Money.SE a CM posted a [Questionnaire](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2114/2015-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire) for the candidates. Will such a questionnaire be useful or practical for the MESE election?

Comment: I think this is a great idea!

Comment: That idea also came up on https://matheducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/595/announcing-a-pro-tempore-election#comment1552_595 It seems that SE is too busy to do it, but we can do it. In a way it's maybe up to the sitting mods to do it when SE says they won't so I'll go ahead.